# Python slicing with and operator between two dates

Tags: python

I want to get values of which are between two dates.

```
df[(df['Meeting Date']>"2022-06-01" & df['Meeting Date']<"2022-07-01")]
```

Meeting date is in correct type (datetime)

this is my error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'DatetimeArray'
```

Comment: Hey, not sure if this is exactly what you wanted, but using time module, you could take two times, using time.time(), subtract the value between them, use the random function to get a random value between 0 and the subtracted value, add this to the initial time, convert it into local time, and the use asctime to put it in a readable format

Answer (score 1):

You need to put parentheses around each statement

```
df[((df['Meeting Date']>"2022-06-01") & (df['Meeting Date']<"2022-07-01"))]
```

Some additional information as to why you need to this in the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Since you are using boolean vectors, each side of the statement resolves to a boolean vector, you need to use parentheses for each statement

Answer (score 1):

You can also try below, more inlined with SQL using **between**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['01-01-2022','02-01-2022','03-01-2022','04-01-2022']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df[df.date.between('01-01-2022','03-01-2022', inclusive="both")]
```

Output:

[image]

You can read more about **inclusive** here
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html